# Return multiple node properties under one alias

Tags: neo4j

My part of query looks like:

```
RETURN user.username as createdBy
```

I want something like this:

```
RETURN (user.username, user.profilePicture) as createdBy
```

Where in result I will get createdBy as an object with properties username and profilePicture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Neo4j 3.1.x, you can use map projection to only return interested properties of a node:

```
RETURN user {.username, .profilePicture} as createdBy
```

If you're using 3.0.x, you can explicitly return a map with the properties you want:

```
RETURN {username:user.username, profilePicture:user.profilePicture} as createdBy
```